# MySQL trying to select the same column twice, but it only returns the value once (no join)

Tags: mysql

What I am trying to do is to get the same column result twice with a single query.

```
SELECT appellation FROM persona WHERE character_id IN (853,12,853) ORDER BY FIELD(character_id,853,12,853)
```

This returns the result:

```
character_id | appellation
---------------------------
853          | John Cena
12           | Chris Brown
```

But what I am looking for to return is:

```
character_id | appellation
---------------------------
853          | John Cena
12           | Chris Brown
853          | John Cena
```

Is there a way in MySQL to get that result?

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth its 8.0.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you can provide a values table and join persona from it:

```
select character_id,appallation
from (select null cid where 0 union all values row(853),row(12),row(853)) cids
join persona on character_id=cid
```

(left join if you want rows even if there's no matching persona)

The `select...where 0` is just to give the column a meaningful name.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zcx4JzVi)

Note that you will not necessarily get them in the order specified in the list; to do that you need to provide something to order on:

```
select character_id,appallation
from (select null cid, null roworder where 0 union all values row(853,1),row(12,2),row(853,3)) cids
join persona on character_id=cid
order by roworder
```

Comment: it works, but is it able to work without a "join"?

Comment: No, it is not .

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result using `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM (    
    SELECT character_id, appellation, CONCAT(character_id, '-1') AS identifier FROM persona WHERE character_id IN (853,12)
    UNION 
    SELECT character_id, appellation, CONCAT(character_id, '-2') AS identifier FROM persona WHERE character_id IN (853) 
) AS tmp ORDER BY FIELD(tmp.character_id, 853,12,853)
```

It seems strange that you want the same row twice though...

Comment: I'm using 8.0.20, union all is not correct syntax

Comment: Hmm, I see. In MySQL 8.0.19 > UNION ALL is the same as DISTINCT.

Comment: I updated the answer to create unique rows.

Comment: @ValeriuCiuca it's a syntax error (whether union or union all or union distinct) because the order by is meaningless; only the union as a whole can have an order.  you can add parens: `(select ... order by ...) union all ...` but the order by isn't guaranteed to have any effect.

Comment: nothing to do with distinct vs all.  `In MySQL 8.0.19 and later, UNION ALL and UNION DISTINCT work the same way when one or more TABLE statements are used in the union.` in the doc doesn't apply since there are no TABLE statements here

Comment: I updated the answer with ORDER BY FIELD(tmp.character_id, ...) - I tested the order, and seems to work.